# using max and limit in a compund MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple process I'm trying to do in a single SQL statement.

I've got a table of players (called tplayers) with columns indicating what their userid and tourneyid are, as well as a "playerpoints" column.  I've also got a table called "tscores" which contains scores, a userid and column called "rankpoints" - I want to take the top 3 rows per player with the highest rankpoints and put that value in the corresponding user record in tplayers -- all for a specific tourneyid.

Here's the query:

```
update tplayers p set playerpoints= 
  ( 
    select sum(b.mypoints) y from 
      ( 
        select scorerankpoints as mypoints from tscores t where t.tourneyid=p.tourneyid and p.userid=t.userid and t.scorerankpoints>0 order by scorerankpoints desc limit 3 
      ) as b 
  ) where p.tourneyid='12'
```

This generates this error:  Unknown column 'p.tourneyid' in 'where clause'

I'm basically looking to take the top 3 values of "scorerankpoints" from table tscores and put the summed value into a column in table tplayers called playerpoints,

and I want to do this for all players and scores who have the same tourneyid in their tables.

It appears that the inner reference to p.tourneyid is undefined...   Is there a way to do this in a single statement or do I have to break it up?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a problem resolving correlated references that are more than one layer deep.  This is a hard one to fix.

The following uses variables to enumerate the rows and then choosing the right rows for aggregation in an `update`/`join`:

```
update tplayers p join
       (select ts.userid, sum(ts.scorerankpoints) as mypoints
        from (select ts.*,
                     @rn := if(@userid = userid, 1, @rn + 1) as rn,
                     @userid := @userid
              from tscores ts cross join
                   (select @rn := 0, @userid := '') const
              where ts.tourneyid = '12'
              order by ts.userid, ts.scorerankpoints desc
             ) ts
        where rn <= 3
       ) ts
       on p.userid = ts.userid
    set playerpoints = ts.mypoints
     where p.tourneyid = '12' ;
```

Comment: Would you recommend that I just break the statement into separate operations?

It seems to me this behavior is unpredictable so is there any significant performance degradation if I don't do all this in a single compound statement?

Comment: @S.ov . . . I am a fan of putting things into a single query, rather than splitting them.  I don't think there is a significant performance hit with this approach.  However, I must admit that doing two separate queries would probably be just as clear from the perspective of the calling code.